# get the maximum value from 3 vectors

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have 3 variables, called a, b & c each is a float64(5000, ).

I want the maximum value of each row.

```
     a     b      c
     3     4      2
     5     5      4
     3     7      8
```

the result I want

```
    4
    5
    8
```

So I thought I could use the line below,

> myResult = max(a, b, c)

but get this error message

> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

How do I get my desired result?

Comment: You could look through the rows and get the max value from each row. Why does this have to be so complicated?

Comment: @wwii... why the link? The answer was accepted in less than 24 hours. You link seems pointless

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`pandas.DataFrame.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) to to map each row to the [`pandas.Series.max`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.max.html) of that row:

```
print(df.apply(pd.Series.max, axis=1))
```

Output:

```
0    4
1    5
2    8
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using numpy, you can achieve this using stack and max:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array((3, 5, 3))
>>> b = np.array((4, 5, 7))
>>> c = np.array((2, 4, 8))
>>> stacked_matrices = np.stack((a, b, c))
>>> np.max(stacked_matrices, axis=0)
array([4, 5, 8])
```

See https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.stack.html#numpy.stack for more information.

(This answer assumes that the arrays are 1-dimensional.)